# How to "cast" union types elm

Tags: elm

Lets's say I have two type aliases:

```
type alias A = {...}
type alias B = {...}
```

and a union type

```
type Content = A | B
```

and a model type

```
type alias Model= {cont : Content, ...}

init : Content -> Model
init cont = {cont = cont, ...}
```

How do I pass a record of type A to init.

```
a : A
a = {...}
init a
```

throws the following error:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
## ERRORS in Main.elm ##########################################################

-- TYPE MISMATCH ------------------------------------------------------ Main.elm

The 1st argument to function `init` has an unexpected type.

78|               init e
                       ^
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    Content

    A
```

I would imagine that A is a kind of "subtype" of Content. I can't just write

```
a:Content
a = {...}
init a
```

because some of the logic does case analysis on Content

Comment: Are the type aliases A and B, as well as the definition for Content in the same module? That fails compilation with a Duplicate Definition error.

Comment: They aren't in the same module but i'm referencing `type Content = modulename.A | modulename.B`. The problem is that those types can't really be brought in to the module. I could make some kind of proxy type I suppose. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elm's union types are so-called discriminated unions (or tagged unions). The discriminating part is a tag or constructor. In this case I think you want:

```
type Content = TagA A | TagB B
```

Note that the first capitalised name is the tag, and anything else is other types or type variables.

Now you can do:

```
a : A
a = { ... }
init (TagA a)
```

Within `init` you can distinguish the two types by doing:

```
init content =
  case content of
    TagA a -> ...
    TagB b -> ...
```